# Optimization problem, choose n from set where $f(n)$ is maximized and $g(n)$ is minimized

Tags: combinatorics, optimization

Say I have multiple objects in a set, each with a certain value $f$ and $g$ for each object in the set, and I want to select exactly $N$ of these objects from the set such that the sum of $f $is maximized and the sum of $g$ is minimized. What is the name of this optimization problem, and how can I approach solving it efficiently?

Comment: How can you be certain that you can simultaneously achieve a minimum of g's and a maximum of the f's?  You need to formulate this as a single objective.  For example, maximize sum of f's while placing an upperbound (which you specify) on the sum of the g's.  Then, there would be a number of ways to solve the problem.

Comment: @TravisJ What are the ways to solve that problem you specified?

Comment: Look into integer linear programming.  Essentially, you just need to find the best way to formulate the question.  For example, maximize $f\cdot x$ where $x$ is a 0-1 vector and $f$ is the vector containing the values of $f(n)$, subject to constraints $g\cdot x\leq b$ where $g$ is the vector of $g(n)$ values and $b$ is the arbitrary bound you set.  Then also have the constraint that you have exactly $N$ non-zero entries in $x$.

Comment: By the way, integer linear programs can be expensive (computationally) to solve in general.  If you have more information about the structure of the $f(n)$'s or $g(n)$'s then perhaps you can speed it up.  If the problem is relatively small, then it should also not be a problem.

Comment: btw.: the problem @TravisJ stated is a [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). It is well-known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can model your objects as
$$ 
u_i = (f_i, g_i)^\top \quad (i \in \{ 1, \dotsc, n \})
$$
We then define selection vectors from
$$
X = \left\{ x \in \{0,1\}^n \mid \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = N \right\}
$$
The difficult part is the objective. with its two sub objectives.
$$
\max_x f_i x_i \quad \min_x g_i x_i
$$

My attempt would be to first change
$$
\min_x g_i x_i = - \max_x -g_i x_i
$$
While we now have two maximizations, those maximizations are independent,
we might end up with two different optimal $x$.

Right now I see only two roads:
Insisting to find a common optimal $x$, which will likely fail most of the times. Or changing the objective (e.g. weighted combination, or best compromise optimum).

This problem seems to be [multi-objective optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-objective_optimization#Introduction).